# Left Join tag table

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to output a list of "items" which all contain a list of "tags". Since the tags are used for more than one item, I'm using a bridge table called "tag_rel".

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.*, t.name
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = j.id)
                LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
                ORDER by i.id DESC"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

I assume this will give me a list of my items. But how do I output the list of given tags for each Item?

I know I shouldn't make a second query for every single query, i,e:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.*
                FROM items AS i
                ORDER by i.id DESC L"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT t.name
                       FROM tag_rel AS tr
                       LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
                       WHERE tr.item=$row[id]"); 
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

Any tips?

Much appreciated!

Comment: The first query will repeat all the items for each *tag* right? So you may do that logic on PHP. Store item info in a var, in another, concat the tags info. When item changes, print the item and its tags, then start over again.

Comment: Yes.. it should works.

Comment: while item is the same do one thing, else do another thing

Comment: The output is a list of thumbnails, all of which are tagged accordingly. Ie. [IMAGE 1] tagged as: funny, lol, cat [IMAGE 2] tagged as: travel, asia, backpack [IMAGE 3.... I know how to get the rows for the items, but how do I get the list of the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) tagList
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = j.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: so how do I output the list of tags?

Comment: Under `tagList` column you will get all tags for a particular items

Comment: Ok, but I don't actually have a tagList column in my table. Are we on the same page?

Comment: It's not column in your table. It's a output column of my query for each items. Check my query and run it on your database than see, if you exactly found your solution?

Comment: Looks promising :D It's giving me a list of the tags as follows: "tag1,tag2,tag3"